# Insertar firma con canvas desde html en PDF

Tags: pdf, canvas, signature

Tengo un quebradero de cabeza desde hace días, y acudo aquí en busca de la salvación.

Necesito insertar una firma a puño y letra en un PDF desde html con canvas, y ese pdf enviarlo por correo (esta parte la tengo lista)

Lo que me pasa es que se genera la imagen de la firma y esa imagen de firma se envia en el correo como archivo .png a parte

Utilizo la libreria Html2pdf para generar el pdf pero al añadir la supuesta variable con los datos de la imagen en base64 me da este error: 'Uncaught Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\ImageException: Unable to get the size of the image'

Dejo por aquí parte de mi código

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

var wrapper = document.getElementById("signature-pad");

var canvas = wrapper.querySelector("canvas");
var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas, {
  backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
});

function resizeCanvas() {

  var ratio =  Math.max(window.devicePixelRatio || 1, 1);

  canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * ratio;
  canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * ratio;
  canvas.getContext("2d").scale(ratio, ratio);

  signaturePad.clear();
}

window.onresize = resizeCanvas;
resizeCanvas();

</script>
<script>

   document.getElementById('form').addEventListener("submit",function(e){

    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var image = ctx.toDataURL(); // data:image/png....
      document.getElementById('base64').value = image;
   },false);

</script>
```

```html
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="signature_pad.js"></script>

<form id="form" action="submit_check.php" method="post">
<div id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad" >
      <div class="description">Dibujar aqui</div>
    <div class="signature-pad--body">
      <canvas style="width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px black solid; " name="canvas" id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="base64" value="" id="base64">
    <button id="saveandfinish" class="btn btn-success">Guardar y Finalizar</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$img = $_POST['base64'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$fileData = base64_decode($img);
$fileName = uniqid().'.png';

require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/vendor/autoload.php';


use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;

$content = '';
$content .= '
<style>
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
}
table{
width:800px;
 margin:20 ;
}
td{
border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
padding: 10px; 
max-width:520px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
img {
    width: 50mm;
    height: 50mm;
}

</style>';

$content .= '<table>';

$content .= '<tr><td><b>CONTROL DE TRAZABILIDAD</b><br><b>ENVASADO BANDEJAS</b></td><td>Rev 7<br>Fecha:26/09/2019<br>COD:FC_AV_SA_07_01 </td> </tr>';
$content .= '<tr><td>Fecha</td> <td>' . date('d-m-Y') . '</td> </tr>';



$content .= '</table>';
$content .= '<img src="'. $img .'" width="50mm" height="50mm"/>';


// Declaramos el formato del documento PDF
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr');

$html2pdf->setDefaultFont('Arial');
$html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));

$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr');
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);

$separator = md5(time());

$filename = "traza_bandejas.pdf";
$pdfdoc = $html2pdf->Output('', 'S');
?>
```

Comment: Hola Jose. Yo creo que el fallo puede estar aquí: var image = ctx.toDataURL();. Cuando llega la imagen al PHP, has debugado $img a ver que tiene? El error puede ser porqué no puede leer el fichero de origen, quizá porqué no sabe la ruta, la ruta sea incorrecta o, aunque sea correcta, no la puede llegar a leer porqué el formato que llega sea incorrecto. ¿Puedes darme esta info?

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo hacer eso para mostrártelo? Gracias

Comment: Debugar es poner un breakpoint en tu editor y ver que valor tiene aquella variable. Una vez lo hagas ya verás por donde puede venir el problema, es cuestión de ir siguiendo la traza hasta ver donde falla.

Comment: He puesto var_dump($img); y me da esto: string(7240) y a continuación el codigo largo en base64 de la supuesta imagen de la firma (creo)

Comment: Ah, ya veo donde puede estar el problema: $content .= '<img src="'. $img .'" width="50mm" height="50mm"/>'; $img es la cadena en Base64, por eso no puede cargar la imagen y te da error. Debería ser así, $content .= '<img src="'. $fileName .'" width="50mm" height="50mm"/>'; ya que $fileName es la ruta del fichero .png

Comment: Lo he probado y me da este error (es bastante largo lo siento...): Fatal error: Uncaught Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\ImageException: Unable to get the size of the image [5e28449448aca.png] in /var/www/html/forms/calidad/vendor/spipu/html2pdf/src/Html2Pdf.php:1513 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/forms/calidad/vendor/spipu/html2pdf/src/Html2Pdf.php(5763): Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf->_drawImage('5e28449448aca.p...', false) #1 /var/www/html/forms/calidad/vendor/spipu/html2pdf/src/Html2Pdf.php(1439): Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf->_tag_open_IMG(Array) #2

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103565/discussion-between-jose-bonachera-and-ferran-munoz).

Comment: se que han pasado años sobre tu pregunta. pero serias tan amable de informar si pudiste solucionarlo y de que manera. ya que tengo el mismo problema que tu. y no hayo que hacer.